# Reload ngrx store after browser awake-up

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

We're developing an angular application with using redux and ngrx/store.

The app reads a continuous websocket feed of data and update the store with the new data almost every second.

We have this problem: when the user leaves the browser window or even the browser tab, the ws connection gets automatically closed and when coming back to foreground we loose information since the store is not updated in that time and the interface does not have accurate data anymore.

What we do now is to verify if the connection is awaked using this web-worker:

```
addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
  let lastTime = (new Date()).getTime();
  const checkInterval = 2000;
  setInterval(function () {
    const currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    if (currentTime > (lastTime + checkInterval * 2)) {  // ignore small delays
      postMessage('wakeup');
    }
    lastTime = currentTime;
  }, checkInterval);
});
```

Then we empty out the store, resubscribe to websocket and repopulate the whole store with the new data. This is not ideal because the user interface gets emptied out and repopulated and this is visible to the user. (For two seconds or so we have no data at all - until the new information comes in).

We don't want to show spinners either. Now we use a spin loader icon centered on the screen while the store is being repopulated. This is very annoying sometimes at least when using ios devices because if I return after 5 seconds the web-worker above sends "wakeup" in ios.

We want to smoothly subscribe in background and replace the old data with the new data. To use something like a temp store while is subscribing in background, and replace the main store with the temp store while everything is ready in background. Can we just replaces the stores like that? Is there a way to achieve something similar to this?

Thank you!